# The length of the vector returned by COPY_OF_ODEFUN is 1, but the length of the initial condition vector is 2

Tags: matlab

I tried to solve Copy_of_odefun by ode45. And I got the error: The length of the vector returned by COPY_OF_odefun is 1, but the length of the initial condition vector is 2. My code is as follows.

Main Function:

```
clear all; clc;
%% Inpput parameters
lambda = 0.0625;
H = 2.3;
zw_H = 2;
ztop_H = 8;
Cdh = 1.2;
a = 9.6 * lambda;
Cd = Cdh * (1 - exp(-2 * a));
d_H = 0.066;  %% Macdonald, 2000(lambda = 0.05)
%% Running
t = linspace(8,0.01,100);
y0 = [1.75; 0.05];
[t,y] = ode45(@Copy_of_odefun,t,y0);
```

Copy_of_odefun Function:

```
function dy = Copy_of_odefun(t,y)
global H lambda Cd
%% mixing length closure parameter
% within canopy
z_H1 = [0.01 1];
lc_H = [0.2463 0.2463];
lc_dz = [0 0];
% shear layer
z_H2 = [1.01 2];
lm_H = [0.2516 0.7736];
lm_dz = [0.5273 0.5273];
% inertial layer
z_H3 = [2.01 8];
lz_H = [0.7776 3.1736];
lz_dz = [0.4 0.4];
% for whole computation domain
zm_H = [z_H1 z_H2 z_H3];
l3_H = [lc_H lm_H lz_H];
l3_dz = [lc_dz lm_dz lz_dz];
% interpolate to obtain value at each point of t
lx_H = interp1(zm_H,l3_H,t);
lx_dz = interp1(zm_H,l3_dz,t);

% second order translated into one order
dy = [y(2); (-lx_H * H * lx_dz * y(2)^2 / (H^2 * lx_H^2 * y(2)) + 0.25 * y(1)^2 * lambda / H * Cd / (H^2 * lx_H^2 * y(2)))];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in global variables. You need to mark them both in function and main script. Just add

`global H lambda Cd`

to the main script and it will run.

There is also problems with second parameter for `ode45` - it should be just `[8, 100]`, not the vector with all needed values of `t`. Some good examples may be found in [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html). There might be some other problems in code - it gives `NaN` for most `y` values.

Comment: yes, the problem may lie in t. t in my case is actually [0.01 8]. But the initial conditions are applied to 8, which is tf in my case. So I have to write t = linspace(8,0.01,100) or [8,0.01], which won't work out. Do U have any ideas about this situation?

Comment: @PanCheng [8,0.01] should be ok, here is a link with such example. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/64854-how-to-give-a-final-value-to-solve-an-ode-s-instead-of-the-standard-initial-values